# How do I prevent ANT from closing batch file?

Tags: selenium, ant

I have a .bat file to start selenium grid and I want it to stay open. I read the documentation on the ANT page but tried couple things but cant figure it out. This is what i have so far. It says it executed it but i cant tell.

```
<project>
 <target name="runBatch">
    <exec executable="cmd" fork="true" spawn="true">
        <arg value="startGRID.bat"/>
    </exec>
 </target>
</project>
```

This is what startGRID.bat looks like when i run from command prompt.
[image]

Comment: Define what you mean by "stay open".  This isn't normally how batch scripts work.

Comment: it is suppose to start Selenium Grid, i want it to stay open(or continue running) until all of the test needed to be run can execute.

Comment: Does the script do that now?  If you simply run it in the console.

Comment: yea ill add a snip of what it looks like

Comment: I don't think you want to fork or spawn this script.  I don't have a windows environment to easily test though.

Comment: I tried without both but get the same result.

Comment: just tried to see if it was doing anything by changing the name of the file in the build.xml to something that didnt exist and still said it succeeded so guessing something else is wrong also

Comment: failonerror:  Stop the buildprocess if the command exits with a return code signaling failure. Defaults to false.

Answer (score 0):

so i got it to start but now i need it to start in another prompt.

```
<project>
<target name="startGRID">
    <exec dir="." executable="cmd">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -role hub"/>
    </exec>
</target>

</project>
```